# mysql 8.0.26 - stored procedure name length issue (25 Chars) only

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have found a very odd issue with mysql 8.0.26.
If I try to either create a procedure via the command line interface (mysql shell) or via a sql script, if the stored procedure name is 25 characters long the mysql shell hangs!
24 characters is fine, and 26 is fine, just 25, how every odd.

john

Comment: seems fixed in [8.0.27](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b4b75fb3c10cc1ddc8625dde7a96217b)

Comment: Please provide the procedure name.

Comment: the procedure name is spInsertAviaryDoorStatus